# Run-Time Check Failure #0 – The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call

Tags: c++

I use windows 7， when I build a C++ win32 console project to exe and run it， error occurs：
[image]

This program is to open the testengine and read some data from the bluetooth chip（CSR3026）.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int iHandle = 0;
    int iTimeout = 0;
    typedef int (*tepsread)(int handle, int keyId, int valueLen, int *value, int  *readLen);
    typedef int (*opentestengine)(int transport, char* transportDevice, int dataRate, int retryTimeOut, int usbTimeOut);
    typedef int (*closetestengine)(int handle);
    char data[50] = {0};
    int v;
    int r;

    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"TestEngine.dll");
    opentestengine openTestEngine = (opentestengine)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "openTestEngine");
    closetestengine closeTestEngine = (closetestengine)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "closeTestEngine");
    do
    {
      cout << "Trying to connect..." << endl;
      iHandle = openTestEngine(2, "COM5", 115200, 1000, 0);
      iTimeout += 1000;
    } while(iHandle == 0 && iTimeout < 5000);

    if(iHandle != 0)
    {
      cout << "Connected!" << endl;

      // Perform all your testing here
      tepsread pFun = (tepsread)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "tePsRead");
      cout << pFun(iHandle, 10191, 32, &v, &r) << endl;

      closeTestEngine(iHandle);
    }

    FreeLibrary(hDLL);
    cout << v << endl;

    return v;
}
```

1 open the testengine via serial port 5 to communicate with the chip.

2 Call tePsRead function in testengine.dll to read value in 10191 from chip.

I have changed to the __cdecl calling convention， but the same error remmains：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28URH.png)

Comment: The error message says it quite clearly: the library is providing function in calling convention A but your program is calling them with calling convention B. More about calling conventions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2017.

Comment: Did you look at any of the other 5 dozen of questions with the same error message? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Run+Time+Check+Failure%22+%22The+value+of+ESP+was+not+properly+saved+across+a+function+call%22

Answer (score 1):

The error message says you call a function after you cast it wrongly to change its signature

So the signature of at least one of the function *openTestEngine, closeTestEngine* or *tePsRead* is not the one you suppose

So

- *tePsRead* is not `int tePsRead(int, int, int, int *, int  *);`
- and/or *openTestEngine* is not `int openTestEngine(int, char*, int, int, int);`
- and/or *closeTestEngine* is not `int closeTestEngine(int);`

Comment: the return and parameter types, and/or the number of parameters, because of that there is an inconsistency in the stack

Comment: That's the function signature (or wide: declaration), not a "profile".

Comment: sorry for my bad English, I am only a French guy, in French all these 3 words can be used ;-). I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for changing the answer. The list at the end of the answer now makes it much clearer.

Comment: How could fix this signature changing problem？

Comment: @liyuting if the signature is not the right one that create an inconsistency in the stack, the quantity of data push on the stack by the caller is not what supposes the called function, the called function get wrongly the arguments from the stack and may be the return address etc. You **must** respect the called function signature when it is called. When you open a door do you use any key or the key corresponding to the lock ?